# Why does gdb evaluate sqrt(3) to 0?

Tags: c, eclipse, math, gdb

The square root of 3, as estimated by Wolfram Alpha:

```
1.7320508075688772935274463415058723669428052538103806280558...
```

When I do `sqrt(3)` in C, it evaluates to 0. Why?

**EDIT4**: here's how you can reproduce this issue in GDB. Create `test.c` as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                                      
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  printf("sqrt(3): %f\n", sqrt(3));
  return 0;
}
```

Compile:

```
gcc -O0 -g -Wall -pedantic -ansi -lm -o test test.c
```

Run debugger:

```
gdb test
```

Enter this at console:

```
(gdb) break test.c:6
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400578: file test.c, line 6.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/pdedecker/Desktop/test   
Breakpoint 1, main () at test.c:6
6         printf("sqrt(3): %f\n", sqrt(3));
(gdb) print sqrt(3)
$1 = 0
(gdb) s
sqrt(3): 1.732051
```

My GDB version is `GNU gdb (GDB) SUSE (7.1-3.12)`.

Comment: Show us the code you're using to get this result.

Comment: Are you including `<math.h>`?

Comment: +1 Jeremiah, I remember the old ages I faced that error too :)

Comment: @Pieter - please post a functional program that shows your problem, including your #include statements, variable declarations, how you're assigning results...

Comment: Yes, I did include `math.h` and I added the appropriate `-lrt` flag.

Comment: @Pieter: Does `sqrt(3.0)` work?  And which debugger are you using?  Try a `printf` in your own code.

Comment: Obviously, Wolfram Alpha is wrong. \*shrug\*

Comment: I meant `-lm`, of course. My bad. I have been toying with semaphores a lot lately.

Comment: Maybe your debugger isn't evaluating the expression properly.

Comment: I tried reproducing my problem in a simple C program, but no luck so far. Trying printf in my program.

Comment: There's no `sqrt` prototype that accepts integers. Could that be part of the problem?

Comment: @Pieter: The compiler/debugger are supposed to insert a cast to `double` automatically; maybe the debugger is failing to do that.

Comment: I recommend that you include what debugger you are using and also edit the title of your question and your tags because your problem really has nothing to do with C at all.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse. I added a screenshot to the question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is not the missing function declaration (which isn't missing, since you did include `<math.h>`).

The problem is missing debug info for the `sqrt` you are actually using. Without that debug info, GDB has no clue what parameter type to pass to `sqrt()`, and what it returns.

You can get the required debug info on many Linux distributions by installing libc-debuginfo package. Here is what I see on such a system:

```
gdb -q ./a.out
Reading symbols from /tmp/a.out...done.
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400558: file t.c, line 6.
(gdb) r

Breakpoint 1, main () at t.c:6
6     printf("sqrt(3): %f\n", sqrt(3));
(gdb) p sqrt
$1 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x7ffff7b7fb50 <__sqrt>
```

Note: "no debug info"

```
(gdb) p sqrt(3)
$2 = 0
(gdb) p sqrt(3.0)
$3 = 0
```

Note: matches your behavior.
What `sqrt` functions *do* have debug info?

```
(gdb) info func sqrt
All functions matching regular expression "sqrt":

File ../sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/e_sqrt.c:
double __ieee754_sqrt(double);

File s_csqrt.c:
complex double __csqrt(complex double);

File ../sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/e_sqrtf.c:
float __ieee754_sqrtf(float);

File w_sqrtf.c:
float __sqrtf(float);

File s_csqrtf.c:
complex float __csqrtf(complex float);

File ../sysdeps/i386/fpu/e_sqrtl.c:
long double __ieee754_sqrtl(long double);

File w_sqrtl.c:
long double __sqrtl(long double);

File s_csqrtl.c:
complex long double __csqrtl(complex long double);

File ../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/mpsqrt.c:
void __mpsqrt(mp_no *, mp_no *, int);

File w_sqrt.c:
double __sqrt(double);

(gdb) p __sqrt
$4 = {double (double)} 0x7ffff7b7fb50 <__sqrt>
```

Note: `__sqrt` is at the same address as `sqrt`, but GDB knows its type!

```
(gdb) p __sqrt(3)
$5 = 1.7320508075688772
(gdb) p __sqrt(3.0)
$6 = 1.7320508075688772
```

One can reasonably argue this is a bug in GDB. Feel free to create one in [GDB bugzilla](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=gdb).

Comment: Interesting. I went ahead and installed `glibc-debuginfo` (hope that's what you meant because I couldn't find libc-debuginfo) and I also see that function prototype for `__sqrt`. `print __sqrt(3)` does return a valid result. I'd report this bug to the GDB devs, except that I have little experience reporting bugs and I don't know enough about the inner workings of GDB to provide useful information to the developers. Anyway, thanks... I'm marking your answer as accepted!

Answer (score 6):

I predict that you didn't do `#include <math.h>`

Without a function declaration, C will default the return value of a function to `int`. A floating point number might come back as 0 depending on the size of your int.  C will also not know how to convert the function argument. It will default to passing the argument as whatever type it happens to be. If you pass an integer to `sqrt()` it will not be converted to a double, but the `sqrt()` function will interpret the bit pattern as `double`.

Comment: +1, not only that the return value goes wild. Also the argument is not converted to `double` if there is no prototype. So `sqrt` would see some weird bit pattern that it interprets as `double` and then returns a double in a register or and the caller takes the value in some other (integer) register.

Comment: I did include `math.h` and I did link with `-lm`.

Answer (score 1):

To call a function without debug info, you must explicitly tell gdb the type for the return and arguments, using a function pointer cast. So, for your example:

```
(gdb) print ((double (*) (double)) sqrt) (3)
$1 = 1.7320508075688772
```

Comment: print (double) sqrt((double)3)

returns 

$6 = 1

I suspect the result is first converted to int and then to double..

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                                      
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  printf("sqrt(3): %f\n", sqrt(3));

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
josh@josh-ubuntu:~/scratch$ ./a.out 
sqrt(3): 1.732051
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in GDB? Launch GDB and enter `print sqrt(3.0)` in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe calling sqrt is not supported ! Maybe because it's a libc function. I don't know the deep reason why, but the following test shows an interesting behaviour:

```
double mysqrt(double x) { return sqrt(x) };
```

Then in a gdb session:

```
(gdb) p mysqrt(3)
$1 = 1.7320508075688772
(gdb) p sqrt(3)
$2 = -1209775368
```